# Is it necessary to close a file number of time it is opened in program?

Tags: c, file-handling

If file is opened using fopen() and in different mode then is it necessary to close it number of time or it can be closed once at end of code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `open` function is the underlying primitive for the `fopen` and `freopen` functions, that create streams.

```
int open (const char *filename, int flags[, mode_t mode])
```

which creates and returns a new file *descriptor* for the file named by `filename`. The argument `mode` is used only when a file is created, but it doesn’t hurt to supply the argument in any case.

So whenever an `open` or `fopen` called a new file *descriptor* is created and these *descriptors* stay allocated until the program ends.

The function `close` or `fclose` closes the file descriptor fields. Closing a file has the following consequences:

- The file *descriptor* is de-allocated.
- Any record locks owned by the process on the file are unlocked.
- When all file *descriptors* associated with a pipe or FIFO have been closed, any unread data is discarded.

If you `open` or `fopen` and don't `close`, then that descriptor won't be cleaned up, and will persist until the program closes.

The problem will be severe if there are a lots of calls of `open` or any file can potentially be opened multiple times (without closing each time), then the descriptors will be *leaked*, until the OS either refuses or unable to create another descriptor, in which case the call to `fopen` fails and program can crash.

On most POSIX operating systems, including Linux and Os X, each process is allocated a fixed table of file handles, or file descriptors. This is typically about 1024 handles. When you try to open 1025th file descriptor the operating system kills your process.

The problem is almost certainly that you are leaking file handles. That is, handles are being opened, and after you are done with them they are not closed.

To avoid the descriptor *leak*, you must need to `close` or `fclose` before a file is reopened each time.

Take a look what GNU described about [Opening and Closing Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Opening-and-Closing-Files.html).

Comment: You say here descriptor leak . What does that exactly mean ?

Answer (score 4):

Each time you open the file, you are going to receive different file descriptors or file handles. So you have to close each file handle using `fclose()` if opened via `fopen()` or `close()` if opened via `open()`.

Comment: ... or `close()` if opened via `open()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to close all of them.

When you use `open`-family syscalls, they return you a `file-descriptor` 
(`fopen` returns `FILE*` which is basically a struct that containts the file descriptor. Have a look on the FILE definition).

```
typedef struct 
{
 short level ;
 short token ;
 short bsize ;
 char fd ; <-- here
 unsigned flags ;
 unsigned char hold ;
 unsigned char *buffer ;
 unsigned char * curp ;
 unsigned istemp; 
}FILE ;
```

As a result `fopen()` will you give you two different FILE* (and different file-descriptors obviously) that you should `close()/fclose()` finally.

Comment: ty it explains well . But what should I do to avoid such thing ?

Comment: I do not think it is too bad to just hold two file descriptors instead of one, and close both them. That really depends on what you are trying to do.